# Possible to run multiple versions of Xcode in different terminals at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, github-actions

### Context

We are using self-hosted runners in github. We have multiple runners installed on the same mac mini. Now we want to isolate the binaries for the runners for cleaner worksace.

### What we have tried so far

[RobotsAndPencils/xcodes](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes)  looks like a good solution to install and switch between multiple versions of Xcode.

We can list the different xcode versions available using the following

```bash
╰─ xcodes list | grep -i installed
12.0.1 GM (12A7300) (Installed, Selected)
13.0 (13A233) (Installed)
```

To install a particular version of xcode (Note that task took around 1h and 22 mins to complete)

```bash
╭─  ~/tmp/test -------------------- 1 ✘  took 37m 0s --- 2.7.2 ---- at 17:04:52 -
╰─ xcodes install 12.0.1


Downloading with urlSession - for faster downloads install aria2 (`brew install aria2`)
(1/6) Downloading Xcode 12.0.1-GM+12A7300: 100%
(2/6) Unarchiving Xcode (This can take a while)
Using regular unxip. Try passing `--experimental-unxip` for a faster unxip process
(3/6) Moving Xcode to /Applications/Xcode-12.0.1-GM.app
(4/6) Moving Xcode archive Xcode-12.0.1-GM+12A7300.xip to the Trash
(5/6) Checking security assessment and code signing
(6/6) Finishing installation

Xcode 12.0.1-GM has been installed to /Applications/Xcode-12.0.1-GM.app

╭─ ~/tmp/test ----------------------- took 1h 22m 17s ---- 2.7.2 --- at 09:58:02 --
```

Switching between multiple versions of xcode

```bash
╰─ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

Xcode 12.0.1
Build version 12A7300

╰─ xcodes select 13.0
Selected /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

╰─ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

Xcode 13.0
Build version 13A233
```

### Challenge

We want to have multiple versions of Xcode running at the same time.
When I open two terminal sessions, the first one should be running version A (which will be used by Github runner A) and the second terminal session should be running version B (which will be running version Github runner B)

Is this possible somehow?
Perhaps I need to create two different users for isolation? I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution with just one user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a per-shell Xcode version you can use the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable.

`export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode-14.1.app`

To switch between multiple system-wide Xcode version, you can use:

- xcodes:

  `brew install xcodesorg/made/xcodes`

  1. xcodes action.

     `xcodes select 14.1`
  2. or with a .xcode-version file at the root of your project.
- or xcversion (*depecrated*):

  `xcode-select --install`

  `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-14.1.app`

Answer (score 0):

`xcodes` supports the `.xcode-version` file where you can specify the version of Xcode needed by the project in the current directory, much like `.ruby-version`.

However, when I run `xcodes select` it prompts for my password every time I open a new terminal window, whereas `xcversion` (now deprecated by Fastlane which I use) used to not prompt for a password.